# While trying to use the "fill_between" the following error is given" Input passed into argument "'y2'"is not 1-dimensional."

Tags: python, matplotlib, fill, between

I am going through the Python Crash Course text and am receiving the error "Input passed into argument "'y2'"is not 1-dimensional" when attempting to use the fill_between portion of matplotlib. I am not sure why.

I have tried this in PyCharm and Anaconda, but receive the error in both IDE's. I'm fairly new to programming and so far have not ran into any issues when following the steps provided in the text, until now. 
In both instances I am using Python 3.7 and Matplotlib 3.0.1

As a side note, I'm also not sure why all the months are not showing on the x-axis, but that is a separate issue.

```
    # Create a program where you import weather data from a csv file

# import the csv file, matplotlib(for visualizing), and datetime
import csv
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

# Create a variable that states the name of the file
filename = 'sitka_weather_2014.csv'
with open(filename) as file:
    # passes the file as an argument to create a reader object
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    # keeps reading until there are no more rows
    header_row = next(reader)

    # Get high temperatures and their dates from the file
    dates, highs, lows = [],[],[]
    for row in reader:
        current_date = datetime.strptime(row[0], "%Y-%m-%d")
        dates.append(current_date)
        high = int(row[1])
        highs.append(high)
        low = int(row[3])
        lows.append([low])

# Plot Data
fig = plt.figure(dpi=250, figsize=(10,6))
plt.plot(dates, highs, c='red',alpha=0.5)
plt.plot(dates,lows, c='blue', alpha=0.5)
plt.fill_between(dates,highs,lows, facecolor='blue',alpha=0.1)
# Format Plot
plt.title("Monthly High Temperatures-2014", fontsize=24)
plt.xlabel('',fontsize=10)
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('Temperature (F)',fontsize=16)
plt.tick_params(axis ='both', which='major',labelsize=16)
plt.show()
```

I expect the shade to show between the high and the low lines. However only the high and low line graphs show in Anaconda, and the program errors will not show the graph in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be the `lows` list which is multi dimensional because you are appending each element as a list using `[low]`. Try replacing

```
lows.append([low])
```

by

```
lows.append(low)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are treating `low` as a list when you have already appending it into a list. There is no need to put brackets around low in the process of appending the value into the list. To fix the problem change the line

```
lows.append([low])
```

To:

```
lows.append(low)
```